# Precompiled Single-Page-Apps in Phoenix App

Tags: single-page-application, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a pre-compiled ember.js app (which fronted-js-framework shouldn't matter here), which basically consists of a folder with a index.html file, and a few js/css assets.

I placed this folder under /priv/static in my phoenix app, and tried to get the routing to serve it... without success so far. I'm on phoenix version 0.17.1 (same as 1.0 afaik). I tried the following steps, in that order:

- In endpoint.ex, I removed the `only: ~w(...)` filter.
- Implemented a bare minimum controller with a single action to serve the file: 

  `def index(conn, _params) do
    redirect conn, to: "/my_app/index.html"
  end`
- added the controller to my routes.ex: 
  `get "/my_app", MyCustomController, :index`

None of the above steps worked so far, I only get the Error `no route found for GET /my_app/index.html`. How could I solve this Issue? I just want to map the URL `"/my_app"` (or, if nothing else works, `"/my_app/index.html"`) to the path `priv/static/my_app/index.html` within my phoenix app. Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

The basic workflow I try to implement is the following:

I have different developers that build some ember.js SPAs in their dedicated folder, located in `$phoenix_root/apps/`. So I have a developer building `$phoenix_root/apps/my_app` with ember and ember-cli. This developer uses `ember server` while developing his app, and has `mix phoenix.server` running in the background, because the phoenix app itself exposes the required data as an RESTful API.

After each implemented feature, the frontend developer types `ember build [...]`, this task compiles the whole ember.js frontend app into a single folder, with a index.html file and some assets, and moves this folder to `$phoenix_root/web/static/assets/my_app`. Then phoenix (or, brunch) triggers, and copies this stuff *as-is* to `$phoenix_root/priv/static/my_app`, ready to be served like any other asset.

The point is to be able to build a bunch of isolated "frontends" as self-contained packages within a single code base (the phoenix app), while the phoenix app itself has additional (other) stuff to do.

Because the Frontend-Developers auto-generate the SPA everytime, modifying the ever-new index.html file is something I *highly* want to avoid. Performance-wise it would be the best to just serve these SPAs as the static files they are - they initialize on their own inside the user's browser.

I hope this adds some clarification why I do this.

**EDIT 2:**

I have a working solution now, see the example repo I created for demonstration purposes: https://github.com/Anonyfox/Phoenix-Example-Multiple-SPA-Frontends

Necessary modifications to the phoenix app:

- modify `endpoint.ex`' `Plug.Static` to include the SPAs and their assets.
- **restart** `mix phoenix.server` after this!

Neccessary modifications to the ember.js apps:

- add `"output-path": "../../web/static/assets/*my_app*/"` to `.ember-cli`, convenience setting to run `ember build` always with this path
- add `baseURL: '/*my_app*/'` and `locationType: 'none'` to `config/environment.js`
- `rm -rf .git` if you want to have all the code versioned within a single project (the purpose of this question)

Comment: I have done literally the same in a new app and it worked just fine. Do you have a simple app that shows the issue?

Comment: Also, to be double sure, if you change anything in `lib`, you need to restart your app.

Comment: Since you're using emberjs (with separate developers), I would suggest you check this addon for deploy. http://ember-cli.github.io/ember-cli-deploy/docs/v0.4.x/ 

Also check these
- http://blog.abuiles.com/blog/2014/07/08/lightning-fast-deployments-with-rails/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZVYP3cPcWQ

Comment: Just a comment on your question – my personal opinion is that storing `ember.js` (or any other JS framework) project *inside* of backend codebase is bad practice. Just put them in completely separate folders, use ember's scripts to pre-process files, and them with apache/nginx.

Comment: @JoséValim restarting phoenix.server in conjunction with a config-modification of the ember apps did the trick, thank you. I'll update my question with the solution... unfortunately I can't give you the bounty for a comment :)

Comment: I am not here for the bounty. :) I will send my comment as a response for documentation purpose but there is no need to give it to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setup should just work. There is only one caveat: every time you change something in `lib`, you must restart your application.

The only directory that is code reloaded on requests is `web`. In fact, that's the only difference between `lib` and `web` directories. That's why you put long running processes and supervisor in `lib`, because there is no need to code reload them, and everything else goes in `web`.

Answer (score 2):

I think easiest way to replace `web/templates/layout/app.html.eex` with your index html and change assets path inside with `<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>` helpers to grab your ember app js file from static folder.

Router part:

```
scope "/", Chat do
  pipe_through :browser
  get "/", PageController, :index
end
```

And inside action `render conn`.

Comment: I'd want to not do this. The plan ist to have several different frontend-apps later, that are developed independently, and all of them are served from my phoenix app and they all use the same APIs for data exchange.

Comment: You can still use this idea. Instead of put it as layout use it as template. Inside action decide which js app to load via render different ember htmls.

Comment: I clarified what I want to achieve in my edit above, do you have an idea how to achieve this *without* touching the auto-generated index.html files?