# Serving static html (and others) from / in Phoenix Framework

Tags: phoenix-framework, plug

I'm working on an API server implemented with the Phoenix Framework. JSON APIs are served from the `/api/<version>` URL. The server also needs to serve static `.html`  (and others, `.css`, `.js`, etc.) files from `/` : it's actually a little SPA developed in another language and compiled down to HTML5, JS and CSS. The behavior should be:

- `/` should serve the `index.html` file;
- `/some/file.html` should serve the `file.html` file from the `some` directory provided the path exists and 404 if it doesn't;
- URLs like `/some/` should send back a 403 or a 404 to prevent directory listing
- everything under `/api` is managed by dedicated controllers.

The project is generated with `mix phx.new --no-ecto --no-html --no-gettext --no-webpack static`  to get rid of `.css`, `.js` files and of the templates. I also created a `priv/static` directory for the statics assets.

I had to remove `only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)` from the parameter list of `plug Plug.Static` in `endpoint.ex` to have files at the root URL being served. All works fine except the errors:

- a request on `/` displays the Phoenix error page with the log `[debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET / (StaticWeb.Router)`. I added  `{:plug_static_index_html, "~> 1.0"}` so I got rid of that problem, yet invoking `/subdir` sends back Phoenix error page. **I just don't see where and how to tell Phoenix to send back a 403 or a 404 (except for `/`).**
- Invoking a URL on a non-exiting file does not send back a 404 but rather the Phoenix error page. I tried to create a `static` pipeline in `router.ex` but it seems the flow doesn't get there. The documentation states: *If a static asset cannot be found, `Plug.Static` simply forwards the connection to the rest of the pipeline.* but  **I don't see where to put the 404 reply**.

Here are the two configurations I tried:

#### Conf I

```
# endpoint.ex
...
  # Serve at "/" the static files from "priv/static" directory.
  plug Plug.Static.IndexHtml, at: "/"
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/",
    from: :static,
    gzip: false
    # only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
...
```

#### Conf II

I removed every thing concerning static content from `endpoint.ex` and added a `static` pipeline in `router.ex`

```
# router.ex
...
  pipeline :static do
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug Plug.Static,
      at: "/",
      from: :static,
      gzip: false # ,
      # only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
    plug :not_found
  end
  
  scope "/", staticWeb do
    pipe_through :static
  end

  def not_found(conn, _) do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "not found")
  end
...
```

Any hint would be helpful.

### Update on 13th of August 2020

Added a catch all rule on scope `"/"` at the end of `router.ex` and at least I get a 404 for any *wrong* request. I'm just wondering how clean all this is...

```
# router.ex
...
  scope "/", AlaaarmWeb do
    match :*, "/*path", DefController, :error_404
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had your same problem, I was trying to serve a SPA created using create-react-app, and I put all the generated files in the `priv/static` folder.

The only way I find to serve the static index.html file from the root path is the following:

- I had to remove the `only:` option form the `Static.Plug` in the endpoint.ex file as you did.
- Following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37568770/8620481, I adopted a different strategy. Instead of trying to serve the static file directly, I read its content as a string and then serve it from a controller.

In particular, in the `router.ex` file, under the `"/"` scope, I have the following route defined:

```
get "/", PageController, :index
```

In the PageController, I implemented the index method as follows:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  file = File.read!("priv/static/index.html")
  html(conn, file)
end
```

I don't know exaclty what is the mechanic behind the Static Plug, but I found this workaround acceptable for my use case.

I hope this could help you as well.